# Настройка fail2ban против DDOS

Tags: nginx, centos, ddos, fail2ban

Как настроить `fail2ban` против `DDOS`-атаки, если access-логи для всех сайтов находятся на в разных папках?

Comment: В случае настоящей DDoS-атаки fail2ban будет полностью бесполезен.

Comment: Рекомендую подход используя ["ловушки" для моментальной блокировки](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/nginx-honeypot-the-easiest-and-fastest-way-to-block-bots).